# Ruby array eval as argument to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have method:

```
def sum(x, y, z)
 x + y + z
end
```

and array

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

How can one pass the array to sum method?
Actually I need something like:

```
pseudo
sum(arr.each {|i| i})
```

without changing method, and it to work if sum would accept splat, so please do not offer sum(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the splat operator `*` Doing so will automatically assign each value in array to the corresponding named parameter.

```
sum(*arr)
#=> The above will automagically do
#=> x = arr[0]
#=> y = arr[1]
#=> z = arr[2]
```

`ArgumentError` will be raised if more elements are passed.

Comment: cp, if you're not convinced, you can examine `sum`'s parameters with   [Method#parameters](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters):`method(:sum).parameters
 #=> [[:req, :x], [:req, :y], [:req, :z]]`. Note you first need to convert the symbol `:sum` to a method with [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-method).

Comment: *"the rest of values in the `arr` will be ignored, if present"* - an `ArgumentError` is raised if the number of arguments don't match.

Comment: Is it only me that thinks the issue is with the #sum method rather then the way it is called?

Answer (score 0):

As a global method, you could create a sum method that will accept both numbers and arrays using the `*` operator:

```
def sum *numbers
   numbers.flatten.inject :+
end
```

it will accept:

```
sum 1,2,3,4
sum [1,2,3,4]
sum [1,2,3,4],[3,4],8,9
```

The `*numbers` is an array containing all the arguments passed to the sum method (except a block, which the method doesn't accept). That's what the `*` operator does.

The [#inject method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is a really handy shortcut to be used on enumerable objects.